# React Array Reload function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

i create a button that delete element from array and its work good!
but im trying to add another button that reload the array again and show the original with the deleted elements

i want to clone th array and use the handlereload to show the full elements again
without refresh the page or use the simple reload window function

this is with this.props in other component

[image]

**after delete element**
[image]

**now i click on reload the button is work but is return the element undefind
with error**
[image]

Comment: You should not modify state directly but through setState (e.g `this.state.counter2.push()`)

Comment: @LongTranthanh sorry im still new in react i dont understand you can show me what to do?

Comment: you can try solution in answer. I think it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to restore the original state, you need to keep it stored somewhere.
A way of doing it could be:

#### Class component:

```
class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.initCounter = [
      { id: 1, value: 3, img: '' },
      { id: 2, value: 2, img: '' },
      { id: 3, value: 0, img: '' },
      { id: 4, value: 0, img: '' }
    ];
    
    this.state = {
      counter: [...this.initCounter]
    }
    
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleReload = this.handleReload.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleDelete(id) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      counter: this.state.counter.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    })
  }
  
  handleReload() {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      counter: [...this.initCounter]
    })
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

#### Functional component with hooks

```
const initCounter = [
  { id: 1, value: 3, img: '' },
  { id: 2, value: 2, img: '' },
  { id: 3, value: 0, img: '' },
  { id: 4, value: 0, img: '' }
];

const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState([...initCounter]);
  
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setCounter(counter.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  }
  
  const handleReload = () => {
    setCounter([...initCounter]);
  }
  
  // ...
}
```